# Getting Started w/ Anaconda

Tags: anaconda

I downloaded Anaconda for a class assignment.

The assignment says to type "condas" in Window's Command Prompt to test if Anaconda has successfully installed , but when I do, the command prompt gives the message:

'condas' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I've tried the same thing with "conda" and gotten the same result.

As far as I can tell, I need Anaconda to create Jupyter notebooks, which I can do using the Anaconda Prompt that comes included with Anaconda.

But why is my command prompt not recognizing condas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Anaconda on Windows does not install itself in a way that makes it accessible from Command Prompt on windows. Instead it creates a special command line application called Anaconda Prompt.

Search for and start Anaconda Prompt from the start menu and use that instead of regular command prompt.

Comment: Thank you- I tried that, but I neglected to put it in the question. I've since edited the question.

Comment: @AwfulPersimmon During the installation of Anaconda, the installer asks whether one would like to add conda to windows Path variable, which is necessary if one wishes to use it from command prompt or powershell. By default, in windows, Anaconda advises users not to do so. If you wish to, you can reinstall anaconda, or manually add conda to the windows Path variable.Google is your tool.

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree that Google is my tool, and I noticed the path variable  option you mentioned (and wondered if it fulfilled the function you say it does). I suppose I could have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda and tried selecting it, but the class I'm in instructs participants to install anaconda and accept the default settings (which do not include the path variable option), so I'm guessing the class was made when an older distribution of Anaconda's installer was going around. Thanks for taking the time to clarify this!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AnacondaX and AnacondaX\Script to path. You can do that in CMD. E.g. If I have Anaconda3 installed on C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3, you can set path with this command

```
SETX PATH “%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3; %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts”
```

If you close CMD and reopen it, all should work.